# How can I hide the closest element with a specific class?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, closest

I want to hide `.panel` when the checkbox is checked. But it is not hiding:

```js
 $(".done").on("change", function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).closest(".panel").hide;
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="panel" style="background:#f4f4f4;">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:45px">
                    <span class="handle ui-sortable-handle">

                    </span>
                    <input class="done" type="checkbox">
                </td>


                <td>
                    <span  style="min-width:100px;min-height:20px;margin-left:0px">Please hide this on check</span>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</li>
```

Comment: `.hide` is missing the `()`. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo: Call the function `hide()` instead of `.hide`

```js
 $(".done").on("change", function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).closest(".panel").hide();
   } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="panel" style="background:#f4f4f4;">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:45px">
                    <span class="handle ui-sortable-handle">

                    </span>
                    <input class="done" type="checkbox">
                </td>


                <td>
                    <span  style="min-width:100px;min-height:20px;margin-left:0px">Please hide this on check</span>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</li>
```

Comment: Oh! I was so focused that something was wrong with the "closest" that I just totally overlooked this...

Comment: Haha, no problem, could you please accept my answer if it works now?

Answer (score 0):

Call me stupid but you forgotten hide**()** parenthesis jajajja, here is a [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8g308131/)

```
$(".done").on("change", function () {
console.log($(this), $(this).closest(".panel"));
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).closest(".panel").hide();
   } 
});
```